# MySQL query to update list counts

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a MySQL problem which I'm struggling to solve.

I have two tables. The first is a table of many thousands of garden items each with a groupid, with many items falling into any given group id. The second table is a summary table, simply listing the groupids and the count of items in each.

I need a query that will regularly update this second table o be run as part of a batch process overnight.

So far I have got this far - the first query selects the groups and counts in the first table and next to them what the new counts should be - I am not sure how to complete it:

```
SELECT l.listid,l.subscribecount,count(ls.listid) 
FROM `lists` as l,`list_items` as ls 
where l.listid=ls.listid
group by listid;

update lists    
left join list_items on
    lists.listid = list_items.listid
set
    lists.subscribecount = count(list_items.listid);
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am pretty new to mysql.

Comment: So what table to you want to update? `lists`?

Comment: Have you considered making the second table a view?

Comment: I would like to update lists Mureinik.

Comment: Eric, I'm not sure how I would make use of views to solve the problem. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: A view is like a table, but is just a query from another table or tables, so if the second table is really just summarizing information in the first table you may be able to make the second table just a view.  If you think that might work.  If it has unique information not in other tables a view would not be a good choice though

Comment: It will potentially have additional info Eric - so a view will be a problem.

Comment: Ok, so the query you show, is that how you extract the information you want to use in the update from the first table?  What does the second table look like?  Can show the columns in that table, and especially the ones you'd like to update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the update-join syntax:

```
UPDATE lists l
JOIN   (SELECT   listid, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
        FROM     list_items 
        GROUP BY listid) li ON l.listid = li.listid
SET    l.subscribecount = cnt
```

Comment: Works perfectly !  Thank you v much Mureink !